# how to prevent jquery UI ajax tabs send request back to server endlessly in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I got a issue like this:
I am using Rails 3.2.9 and jqueryUI 1.9.0
I had a tabs UI and use ajax for each tab.
the html and Javascript code is like this:

```
<!-- index.html.erb -->
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="home/page1">page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="home/page2">page2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- page1.html.erb-->
<p>this is page 1</p>

<!-- page2.html.erb-->
<p>this is page 2</p>
```

and in home.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
});
```

so, when I start the server, and try to activate any tab, the front end will keeping send the requests back to server. does any one know what happened on this?

Thank you

---

**Update**

I change the home.js like this but still doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
      if ( ui.tab.data( "loaded" ) ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return;
      }

      ui.jqXHR.success(function() {
        ui.tab.data( "loaded", true );
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I still can not find the reason why this happened. A big thank you if some one can figure it out.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show your logs? or the errors you are getting?

Comment: @LeoCorrea: no errors I got, it's just keeping sending the requests back to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you specify `home/page1` and `home/page2` in your href links, it will load them up each time you click on the relevant tab.

Instead you can load the pages up once in `index.html.erb` by rendering partials into your page. If you rename `page1.html.erb` to `_page1.html.erb` and `page2.html.erb` to `_page2.html.erb` you can change your code to:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="page1">
         <%= render 'home/page1' %>
    </div>
    <div id="page2">
         <%= render 'home/page2' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

If you still want to load the pages dynamically when you click each tab but only once, then don't use partials - you can just use the cache option:

```
 $( "#tabs" ).tabs({ 
            cache: true 
            //some other options 
  });
```

Comment: This is a solution, but what if I just wanna to use ajax to achieve this. since the partial may little bit large, so I don't wanna to load all of the partials one time when I just open the index.

Comment: I think this is a different story, I tried cache but it still doesn't work as normal, the page is still keeping send the requests back to server without rest. BTW, cache was deprecated. New API is here: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#added-refresh-method

Comment: @Anar, not sure what is going on here `cache: true` or your `beforeLoad` code should stop tabs from reloading from the server. If you point the tabs at another page on the internet other than your rails server, does it keep reloading those pages?

Comment: @mcannf, Thank you for your following up, if I point the tabs to some other page on internet, it seems works good. I did some change on my project, using the gem "jquery-ui-rails", this will not happened, but I can not use the theme any more. So still cannot figure out why this happened.

Comment: This method not longer exists in the current version of jquery 1.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your controler

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :layout => false }
end
```

That prevented me to keep looping the requests.